# Job search transparency while working

Tags: interviewing, job-search

I am currently employed on a full time contract, but I want to start looking for a job in a foreign country, where I plan to move in the future, just to see the response I get.

Is it possible that the company I apply to will call my current company, or notify them in any other way?

I'm asking, becuase in the latest application I saw the following:

> It is a security company, so all prospective employees will be subject
>   to an extensive background check.

So, how is it really?

Comment: The last time I was job hunting I simply asked companies not to do a background check until that was all that stood in the way of a signed job offer. They were happy to comply.

Comment: They probably will conduct background check/contact your employer after you received and accepted offer from them and this offer will be conditional on positive background check.

Answer (score 2):

Normal practice is that a hiring company will not contact your current company until you say it is OK. This is normally done after you have been interviewed and/or tested, salary and terms have been agreed, and so on. The hiring company then will contact your existing company for references; by then however it should be pretty much a formality and you have got the job unless they find something very bad in your references.